# PHPWord /samples/ files

Tags: php, phpword, phpoffice

I am trying to download the PHPOffice/PHPWord GitHub repository from :

```
 https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/tree/master
```

In the downloaded zip archive I only get the /src/ directory.

How do I download the other directories? I need the samples/ directory files.

Comment: If you downvote my questions at least explain what I'm doin wrong!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of downloading You should try

```
git clone https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord.git
```

Run above command on command line/terminal in wherever folder you want. You will get all the folders you are looking for.

Comment: i have same problem, thax

Answer (score 0):

If you don't usually use git and you want to do it manually:

1. Sign in
2. Open any file from the repository
3. Find below part:

[image]

4. Click on the pencil
5. Choose "Open in github.web"
6. You will be able to see all files and directories in your browser and you can download them just by clicking a right mouse button